# Get net amount by date with SQL Server using Left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm trying to get the net amount by day, using a CTE and my purchases table. The following gives me an error which `calendar.DateValue` is not in group by clause. I'm using a CTE because I can't think of any other way of getting date values of the range. `o.date` is a `datetime` populated with `GETDATE()` upon the order placement, so it contains time as well.

```
WITH calendar AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2013-01-01' AS DATETIME) DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DateValue + 1
  FROM    calendar
  WHERE   DateValue < '2013-12-31'
)
SELECT
    SUM(o.amount) AS total_amount,
    c.DateValue 
FROM 
    calendar c 
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.orders o ON c.DateValue = o.date
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Desired result:

```
DateValue   | total_amount
------------|-------------
2013-01-01  | 219.00
2013-01-02  | 397.00
```

Comment: Dear could you show your table Demo?

Comment: then it wouldn't be left join?

Comment: My SQL Server 2005 talks that cant generate recursively more than 100 rows...

Comment: I'm using MSSQL 2008, someone edited my post from mssql to sql server etc...

Comment: Use `MAXRECURSION` option like here: http://vinay.inkeysolutions.com/2011/05/prevent-recursive-cte-from-entering.html

Comment: The first part of the script works fine. It shows the days, without a problem, all 365 of them. The problem is when I try to get total_amount by date that it won't work.

Comment: Just `GROUP BY CAST(o.dare as INT)`. You no need TCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH calendar AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2013-01-01' AS DATETIME) DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DateValue + 1
  FROM    calendar
  WHERE   DateValue < '2013-12-31'
)
SELECT
    SUM(o.amount) AS total_amount,   
    c.DateValue 
FROM 
    calendar c 
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.orders o ON c.DateValue = cast (o.[date] as date)
group by c.DateValue 
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: This works! thank you, I was missing the cast and the group by?

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast your o.[date] as `DATE` type to get the date part only (no time).

```
WITH calendar AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2013-01-01' AS DATETIME) DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DateValue + 1
  FROM    calendar
  WHERE   DateValue < '2013-12-31'
)
SELECT
    X.total_amount,
    c.DateValue 
FROM 
    calendar c
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT CAST(o.[date] AS DATE) AS order_date, SUM(o.amount) AS total_amount
    FROM dbo.orders o
    WHERE o.[date] >= '2013-01-01' AND o.[date] <= '2013-12-31 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY CAST(o.[date] AS DATE)
) X
ON X.order_date = c.DateValue
```

Comment: If there are no orders, the date wouldn't show and if I'm showing the whole year, it's pretty hard to notice that a day is missing and time consuming if i was to scan through for missing dates. If I order results by total_amount, I can easily see that a date does not have any purchases and find out why certain dates don't perform as well as others

Comment: Ok, in this case you can treat my previous query as inner query and join to your calendar.